# PyDev Code Inspection issue?

Tags: python, pydev

I recently started using PyDev from my project and noticed that code inspection does not complain about when I try to assign to or read values of the attributes that do not exist. For example in the screenshot below, line 10 and line 13 should at lease give me warning that following attributes do not exist. Is this the side effect of Python's dynamic nature?

[image]

Comment: To know that it doesn't exist it would have to execute every possible code path. Even ones that modify `A` from outside of your `test` file. That's simply impossible (maybe not in your example but it would be if you imported something) so the correct answer is "There is no warning because it *could* exist".

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really check if they exist because it takes too much effort i guess. Python code is valid as long as it works. If you refer to a variable that doesn't exist then you have a problem, but how does Python know whether it exist? It needs to run the program first :)

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to an attribute that does not exist is *the* way to define an attribute. This is what you do in your typical `__init__`.

If you define an attribute in your class definition, it's a *different* thing. You define an attribute of a *class*, not of an instance. It's like a static attribute in languages like Java. When you try to access its value, it does resolve via `self`, much like a static attribute would resolve in Java via `this`. When you try to assign it, you define an instance's attribute.

```
class T(object):
    a = 100
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a  # This shadows class's .a

w1 = T(1)
assert w1.a == 1  # Not 100

w2 = T(2)
assert w2.a == 2  # Not 100

assert T.a == 100
```

You can freely assign more attributes to the instance and to the class later on.

```
w1.foo = 100
assert w1.foo == 100

# w2 does not have .foo

def moo(self):
    return self.a * 100

T.moo = moo  # Add a method

assert w2.moo() == 200
```

All this makes static analysis of Python code a pretty involved task. Some things about it cannot be resolved in a way simpler than actually running the code.

Answer (score 0):

this was a deliberate choice on my side when creating code analysis on PyDev...

The major reason for that is given the dynamic nature of Python that analysis check gave many false positives (there are many ways to set attributes on Python).

PyDev still checks for things that are usually more static, such as imports -- and even on the imports which are usually a bit more structured, it's probably the main source of false positives because the code is statically analyzed -- although there's a workaround which involves configuring the interpreter to say modules to be dynamically analyzed by a running interpreter through the **forced builtins**... see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html.

The second reason is that this check is also more processing intensive (when designing the code analysis my major targets were performance and reducing false positives).

Still, I believe you can have those checks done if you enable the PyLint integration (http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pylint.html). PyLint has different targets -- it's somewhat slower but analyzes more things, and I believe it will complain about the issue you outlined (although I haven't tested it here).